# Trouble transferring and maintaining ios app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Currently I am having an issue with publishing an iOS application.

This is the rejection message that we receive from Apple:

> "The Seller and Artist names associated with your app do not reflect the name, "blank," in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement. "

The company I work for is a software company and the ios application we are doing is for one of our clients. According to Apple, our client is suppose to publish the application with their own developer account. We wanted to transfer the application to their own developer account, but us still be enabled to maintained the application. But if we do, how are we going to keep doing updates and future versions on this application. What is the process how this is suppose to be done?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Can you please let us know the steps that you had followed? We are in a similar situation.